# If I create a character with 2 Psionic Classes does he get bonus PP Per day From both?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

I have a Wilder/Psiwarrior Character I have just created and I have a question. Does this character get bonus PP Per day based on both his Wisdom and Charisma? I was unsure when I was reading this and was wondering.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calculate the Power Points granted by each class separately, then combine them to form your total pool.

So yes, it can be said that your Wilder/Psychic Warrior would receive bonus PP for both Wisdom and Charisma, but these bonus PP would be as appropriate for the manifester levels of each class. For example, a Wilder 6/Psychic Warrior 2 with Wisdom 14 and Charisma 18 would have a total PP pool of

35 PP (Wilder base) + 0.5*4*6 PP (Wilder bonus for Cha) + 1 PP (PsyWar base) + 0.5*2*2 PP (PsyWar bonus for Wis) = 50 PP.

[Rules text for reference](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/index.htm#multiclassPsionicCharacters):

> If you have levels in more than one psionic class, you combine your power points from each class to make up your reserve. You can use these power points to manifest powers from any psionic class you have.

Comment: I would tend to agree with this interpretation.  A Wizard/Sorcerer would get bonus spells for both Int and Cha.  Psionicists just have the ability (not without cost) of being able to use a combined point pool.

Comment: Wow you must be Psychic. My Build is exactly that but with 14 Cha and 18 Wis Although I think Ill Switch it. maybe. I dunno Its a Mellee Centric Psionic Character Using the Wilder as the majority Class for the Power Boost from wild Surge.

Comment: Psychic? I prefer the term "Psion". :D

Comment: I'd also consider the possibility of keeping the two pools entirely separate and allowing the player to pull only from the pool for the class's abilities he's using. This prevents a player getting around the low PPs for, say, a Psychic Warrior by buying a level of a class with higher based PPs (for instance Wilder). But... that does add greater bookkeeping.

Comment: @Gaxx: I suspect it's very hard to really accomplish that, since PP growth is non-linear, you're splitting your ability scores, and that's without even mentioning the problems inherent in lost manifesting.

Comment: @Gaxx: For example, a Psychic Warrior 16/Wilder 4 loses 48 PP from missing PsyWar levels. His PsyWar ML is the same due to Practiced Manifester, and if he burns a second feat on it for Wilder, he gains 17+2*Cha PP from Wilder. It's unlikely that this character is going to have 30+ Charisma, so this is a bad trade.